# windows phone 8 video processing

Tags: windows-phone, video-processing

I want to write an app that works with video. So for example i want this app can add watermark to video file. Are there any ways to do it, maybe with C++ and direct3d, or win32 api available for windows phone? I can`t find any examples at the internet. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per my knowledge, **Windows Phone 8 do not have any kind of API to Edit video**.
For that, one need to migrate to **Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT API)** which have API [**Windows.Media.Editing**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.editing.aspx) namespace to play with Video Clips and Compositions.

even I've searched a lot about Video editing API for Windows Phone 8 but couldn't find one.

Hope that helps..!